# Label text not updated correctly when calling multiple on_press functions in kivy

Tags: python, label, kivy

When a save button is pressed, I want to show "data was saved" for some seconds.
It seems that he is calling both functions, but my label-text is not updated like ".send_button_answer.text = 'Data saved'". In the end, the label just shows the dot --> '.'.

My kv-file:

```
Button:
    id: send_button
    text: 'Save data'
    on_press: app.set_variable_to_db("vendor", user_name.text) 
    on_press: root.configuration_save_button_pressed()
Label:
Label:
    id: send_button_answer
    text: "..."
```

My Python code:

```
class TestWidget(TabbedPanel):
    def configuration_save_button_pressed(self):
        self.ids.send_button_answer.text = 'Data saved'
        self.configuration_save_button_pressed_2()

    def configuration_save_button_pressed_2(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        self.ids.send_button_answer.text = '.'
```

Answer (score 1):

`time.sleep` does what it says on the tin: the program does nothing, including updating the gui.

The solution is to work with kivy's clock instead of blocking it. Do `Clock.schedule_once(self.configuration_save_button_pressed_2, 2)` instead, and make that method expect a single argument (it can ignore that argument, but the clock schedule will still pass it).

Comment: Your code was not working but "Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.configuration_save_button_pressed_2(), 2)" was working. Thank you. - But time.sleep is called after updating the first time right? - Maybe could you take my code into your answer for accept the correct answer?